# Retrieving Constants from Server Side using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsom

Is there a way to retrieve a constant from a `Constants.cs` file by using javascript? I can retrieve the my constant in my ascx page using `Constants.Lists.DisplayName.MyList`. I was wondering if I can reuse the same method of calling the list in javascript. I am currently using JSOM and I would need the list name as one of my parameters.

Comment: `Constants.cs` is your custom class?

Comment: Hi Atish, yes it is.

Comment: Have a look into my answer

Answer (score 1):

In .ascx, add Literal:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="MyListName" Mode="PassThrough" />
```

Then in .cs, add value for that control like this, e.g., in `OnInit`:

```
MyListName.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>var myListName='" + Constants.Lists.DisplayName.MyList + "';</script>";
```

Finally in JS, use `myListName` variable like a boss.